# Use MS Sync Framework to sync SQL Server 2012 to Postgres 9

Tags: linux, postgresql, sql-server-2012, microsoft-sync-framework

Has anyone here successfully used the [Microsoft Sync Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb736753.aspx) (see [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb821992.aspx)) to sync between MS SQL Server 2012 and PostgreSQL 9.x?

Can it work when the postgreSQL server resides in a Linux environment?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried it? Link to "MS Sync Framework"? PostgreSQL version? What's the underlying problem you're trying to solve? Please elaborate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: This question was [cross-posted to the PostgreSQL mailing lists too](http://archives.postgresql.org/message-id/1346800280.89623.YahooMailNeo@web163004.mail.bf1.yahoo.com) so if anyone else is looking this up later, check the linked thread for discussion. I'll try to link anything useful here.

Comment: We have a legacy system built on top of .net and sql server and we wanna implement the website redesign on the open sources stack.

Comment: OK, and how does sync framework fit into that? Are you trying to replicate changes in real time between SQL Server and PostgreSQL so you can keep both running in parallel during a migration? Or... ? I'd suggest editing your question to explain a bit more about the what and why, not just the how you've decided is the solution. If you explain the underlying problem you're trying to solve then others might have suggestions for alternative approaches you haven't though of.

Answer (score 1):

there is no PostgreSQL sync provider out of the box, so you will have to write your own.

have a look a the sample Oracle sync provider here: Database Sync: [Oracle and SQL Compact 2-Tier](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Database-Sync-Oracle-and-037fb083)

doesnt matter if your PostgreSQL is in Linux since you're just connecting to it. you dont have to install anything for the sync on the Linux side.